# Angular 2 attribute directive to modify the input host text and value

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need to have an attribute directive that will format the input as dd-mm-yyyy and have it as text value and according javascript date as value. At rc.3 I used `ngFormControl.valueAccessor.writeValue()` and a few other methods. Now in it seems that NgFormControl is gone in the release version. What should i be using now? Here is what I was doing before:

```
<input type="text" format-date2 [ngFormControl]='formControls.dateOfMarriage'>

import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgFormControl} from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
selector: '[format-date2]',
host: {
  '(input)': 'onInputChange()',
  'placeholder': 'dd-mm-yyyy',
 },
})
export class FormatDate2 {

viewValue;
modelValue;
currentValue = '';
el: HTMLInputElement;

constructor(private model: NgFormControl, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
}

ngOnInit() {
 if (this.model.control.value) {
  let d = new Date(this.model.control.value);
  let s = this.pad(d.getDate()) + '-' + this.pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getFullYear();
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(s);
  }
}

pad(n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}

onInputChange() {
  let i = this.el.selectionEnd - this.el.value.length;
  this.format(this.el.value);
  i = this.viewValue.length + i;
  this.model.control.updateValue(this.modelValue);
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.viewValue);
  this.el.setSelectionRange(i, i);
  return false;
}

format(val) {
// some code
//   this.modelValue = 'some value';
//   this.viewValue = 'another value' 
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of `NgFormControl` class use `NgControl` / `@angular/forms`
- Instead of `[ngFormControl]` directive, use `[formControl]`.

You also need to make sure that you `@NgModule.imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]` into whatever module the component using the forms is declared in. This is for using reactive forms, i.e `FormControl`/`FormGroup`, but template forms, just use `FormsModule`. Your example though looks like it's using reactive forms. But your directive will work with template forms also.

Comment: Specifically I used NgControl.control.setValue() and NgControl.valueAccessor.writeValue()